# JQuery affecting Google Chart Display

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

The below code displays a messed-up chart,

```
function() displayGoogleChart() {
    /* displays chart */
}
$("#chartDiv").hide();
displayGoogleChart();
$("#chartDiv").show();
```

[image: problem chart]
But this code displays fine, like so:

```
$("#chartDiv").hide();
$("#chartDiv").show();
displayGoogleChart();
```

[image: fixed chart]
**Why is this happening?**

Comment: It's probably something within displayGoogleChart that is trying to get width or height or some other css value that returns an unexpected value because it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with the methods `google` uses to determine the heights and widths of the various chart items, as @dwaddell commented.

I would try using a container `div` enclosing `#chartsDiv`, and see if the same thing occurs when hiding and showing the containing `div`.